# A circular histogram in R shows incorrect values

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, histogram

I'm trying to recreate a circular plot from [here](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/3369_998f8b2d788e4a0384ae565c4280aa47.html) (a first plot on this page), but the output I just got seems incorrect. The 'last' bar (between 23 and 0) is missing and the 'first' one (between 0 and 1) is unproportionally high. What's more, bars appear 'moved' by one unit to the left, while on the website above the plot seems fine.

Here is a code which I copied from that site. The only difference I made is that I removed `"width=2"` from geom_histogram(), because otherwise it raised an error saying that argument `width` was deprecated.

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)   

set.seed(44)
N=500
events <- as.POSIXct("2011-01-01", tz="GMT") + 
              days(floor(365*runif(N))) + 
              hours(floor(24*rnorm(N))) +  
              minutes(floor(60*runif(N))) +
              seconds(floor(60*runif(N)))

hour_of_event <- hour(events)

eventdata <- data.frame(datetime = events, eventhour = hour_of_event)
# determine if event is in business hours
eventdata$Workday <- eventdata$eventhour %in% seq(9, 17)

ggplot(eventdata, aes(x = eventhour, fill = Workday)) + 
    geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0, 24), colour = "grey") + 
    coord_polar(start = 0) + theme_minimal() + 
    scale_fill_brewer() + ylab("Count") + 
    ggtitle("Events by Time of day") + 
    scale_x_continuous("", limits = c(0, 24), breaks = seq(0, 24), labels = seq(0, 24))
```

Here is what I got:

[image: plot]

Here is a table of the data. You can see that for hour 23 should be a value of 17 instead of 0 like in my plot.

```
table(eventdata$eventhour)
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 
23 22 18 26 28 20 19 21 16 17 20 16 18 22 16 21 24 21 22 27 25 18 23 17
```

Do you have an idea why my plot doesn't show correct values and how I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I propose this solution based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43033628/circular-histogram-in-ggplot2-with-even-spacing-of-bars-and-no-extra-lines) :

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(44)
N=500
events <- as.POSIXct("2011-01-01", tz="GMT") + 
  days(floor(365*runif(N))) + 
  hours(floor(24*rnorm(N))) +  
  minutes(floor(60*runif(N))) +
  seconds(floor(60*runif(N)))

hour_of_event <- hour(events)

eventdata <- data.frame(datetime = events, eventhour = hour_of_event)
# determine if event is in business hours
eventdata$Workday <- eventdata$eventhour %in% seq(9, 17)

df <- data.frame(table(eventdata$eventhour),
                  business_hour = 0:23 %in% seq(9, 17))
colnames(df)[1:2] <- c("hour", "value")


ggplot(df, aes(hour, value, fill = business_hour)) +
  coord_polar(theta = "x", start = 0) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .9)
```

I hope it helps. It doesn't tell you why you have a problem in your case but it gives you a viable solution.

Comment: Thank you. It's not exactly what I wanted, but if only the bars were between hours, not under them, it would be perfectly fine solution.

Comment: I search during a bit of time but I didn't find.. sorry

Comment: No problem, thank you again. In the meantime I found a solution for my original plot anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the issue was caused by arguments of `geom_histogram` and `scale_x_continuous` function.

Instead of this:

```r
geom_histogram(breaks = seq(0, 24), colour = "grey") +
scale_x_continuous("", limits = c(0, 24), breaks = seq(0, 24), labels = seq(0, 24))
```

it should be:

```r
geom_histogram(bins = 24, colour = "grey") +
scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-0.5, 23.5), labels = seq(0, 24))
```

It's still a bit confusing to me why it works only this way, but it finally works...